# How to fetch the POST method with formik using getform.io

Tags: reactjs, post, fetch-api, formik, getform

I/ve made a form with formik on my portfolio (https://alexpowelldev.com/)that im trying to send the data being submitted to getform.io.
For some reason I'm getting a 400 error in the console when submitting which is as folllows:

```
 form data {firstName: 'Alexander', email: 'john@yahoo.com', type: '', comment: 'test kjdfhsdkjfhakjsdfhisafbsdivuabvierbuib'}ContactMe.js:27
```

POST https://getform.io/f/... 400
onSubmit @ ContactMe.js:27
ContactMe.js:33 Response {type: 'cors', url: 'https://getform.io/f/...', redirected: false, status: 400, ok: false, …}

There seems to be some sort of disconnect. Here is the code:

```
const formik = useFormik({
initialValues: {firstName:"",email:"",type:"",comment:"" },
onSubmit: (values) => {
  fetch("https://getform.io/f/...", {
    method: "POST",
    body: values,
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
    },
})
.then(response => console.log(response))
.catch(error => console.log(error))
  console.log('form data', values)
}

 <form 
       onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}
       >
```

Any help would be much appreciated.I can add more context if needed.

edit* I found in the chrome dev tools this message: [image]

However you can see in my initialValues for formik that They all have unique names.

Comment: What request body  format does the API expect? `application/json` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: i changed the "Accept" to multipart/form-data as you suggested and i did get a status code 200, however still waiting for it to arrive in my inbox. oh wait maybe its because im submitting with localhost

Comment: The `Accept` header describes the format you expect the **response** to be. It has no bearing on the request content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a very quick look at the examples on the https://getform.io/ home page, it appears they expect request bodies in `multipart/form-data` format.

To provide this, create a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) instance and add your form values

```js
onSubmit: async (values) => {
  const body = new FormData();
  Object.entries(values).forEach(([ key, val ]) => {
    body.append(key, val);
  });

  const res = await fetch("https://getform.io/f/...", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { accept: "application/json" },
    body,
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    console.error(res.status, await res.text());
  } else {
    console.log(await res.json());
  }
}
```

---

[Looking further](https://docs.getform.io/installations/ajax/sending-submissions-with-ajax/), they also support `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`...

```js
fetch("https://getform.io/f/...", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { accept: "application/json" },
  body: new URLSearchParams(values),
})
```

and even `application/json`

```js
fetch("https://getform.io/f/...", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    accept: "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(values),
})
```

Comment: THANK YOU. I was using the application/json method earlier but i guess i needed to stringify the values first. (?) This was my first time working on submitting forms outside of console.log and I didnt know how much of a pain it was. I guess im just not familiar with it. But that fixed it so i appreciate it very much Phil

Comment: @Mr_Yellow7 you're welcome. There's always two parts to sending data over HTTP... 1) the serialised data (string), and 2) the content-type header describing the format. When using `FormData` or `URLSearchParams`, they provide the serialisation and header for you. To send JSON, you need to provide the header and stringify the data